# Logout From LinkedIN using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am using openid in my asp.net application.For Linkedin ,I have used javascript api I am able login in my site but I want to know how to logout from my site which will automatically logs me out from linkedin also. Pl suggest some solution.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol doesn't allow for you to log the user out of LinkedIn.  You may only log users out of your own site.  This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function

```
function logout() {
        IN.User.logout(function () {
            window.location.href = '/logout.aspx'; 
        });
    }
```

works for logout but when we leave the site ideal for some time, it doesn't work.